# jquery vertical scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

Now, I'm trying to create a vertical scroll.
http://www.chohoh.com/pcs/test.scroll.html

I have quite a few things nested which needs to remain like that but I think I'm unclear on how to tell the jquery file that it needs to scroll between two li classes "white-tikt" and "tan-tikt".

I'm completely baffled why this isn't working. Even if someone can just get me thinking in a different way, I keep trying the same things over and over.

Looking for any resolution, help, tip or advice. thanks!

Comment: The link is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the scroll to plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

You could also try something using the animate functionality:

```
$('#current-div').animate({width: '0px'});
$('#next-div').animate({width: '300px'});
```

Comment: I'm actually going to try that now, shifting gears but I'm not quite understanding what I have to do to get it to vertical scroll with this angle? can you help me out?

Comment: If you look at the demo: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ click on the "jQuery object" on the top demo, it will give you an example of what you need to do ;)

Comment: weird.
that page makes no sense to me. I'd be just as best off copying and pasting random stuff on the page until something works. 
it doens't explain anything!!!

Comment: that demo you sent is the worst example. i think it confused me more. there is no indication anywhere explaining how to vertical scroll a div box. :(

Comment: $.scrollTo('#options-examples', 800);

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding something. 
I'm not sure where I'd put that.
i have this so far.

$('#slideshow').serialScroll({
  items:'li',
  prev:'#screen2 a.galprev',
  next:'#screen2 a.galnext',
  offset:-387, //when scrolling to photo, stop 230 before reaching it (from the left)
  start:1, //as we are centering it, start at the 2nd
  axis:'xy',
  duration:1000,
  
  force:true,
  stop:true,
  lock:false,
  cycle:true, //don't pull back once you reach the end
  easing:'easeOutQuart', //use this easing equation for a funny effect
  jump: false, 
  
 });
 
});

Comment: I got it from here.
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/

there was too much information on that one link you sent me I couldn't make sense of what anyhting was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Div box needs to be overflow:hidden, then you can use [localScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) to scroll between elements.

Try to make your own simple example with some code like:

```
$.localScroll();
```

Does this help any or am I out of my league?

Comment: That could have been helpful too.